# Implement Login in Android

Tags: android, security

I'm trying to make an app where the user must log in with a name/pass combo. However, I'm not entirely sure where to check if the username/pass is valid.

Each time the app is run, should I refresh my copy of the database on the phone before showing the login screen? Or should I pull only after I've validated the login info (via a post sent over https?).

Also I'm wondering about the security of storing a part of the database that contains the username/password combos on the phone. If I hash the password repeatedly with a salt, is there a chance the username/password combo could be viewed easily? What hash algorithm is appropriate? (md5 is weak I've read, as is sha-1, but maybe with repeated iteration it could mitigate sha-1 weaknesses?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Validate the login info (via some HTTP method) before you update the database. If you store any credentials in the phone's DB's, then someone who doesn't hava a login can get access to your data with a rooted phone. Even if you hash the values, someone with a rooted phone can change what's in the database etc..

SHA-2 with a salt is a good bet for security.

Comment: SHA-2 with a good salt will NOT help at all against a dictionary attach or a brute force attack: http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/

Comment: I'd have to agree bcrypt is better for security, however you are still vulnerable to man in the middle and replay attacks if you use HTTP methods. All of this will depend specifically on your scenario and how much security you require

Comment: Yes, no arguments there, SSL/TLS is a must for securely transferring the password.

Answer (score 0):

If you update your database before or after the user uses the login depends on your application concept. I guess the provided data is only meant for users who have a valid login so you should only load/update your database after the login. Otherwise users could download your application, download the database and gain access to the provided data which might be delicate (I don't know what's stored inside, so you have to decide)

Why would you save user data (login) on the phone? This only makes sense if your application runs without internet but this would mean your application would have to store the login data of all users on every phone. That's a horrible idea.

You could use SHA-2 for your passwords but using a salted md5 should be still usable in most scenarios.

Comment: I'm stuck using some 3rd party apis which manage data and I have a lot to learn about them.

Answer (score 0):

I did the process few days ago. You have 2 choices. RESTful services or through json.

I am sending a json via httppost and then hashing the password and authenticating in php(server side)

The problem is that when you are sending json you are sending plain text. There are some tricks around that. You could hash your password on the android app and change the whole logic of your site/database to handle the hashing you chose or through https post. I would suggest the latter. Depends what is easier for you

Comment: encrypting != hashing I think you mixed it up or do you really want to encrypt the passwords?

Answer (score 0):

For the password storage part of your question:

- Do NOT simply hash your password and store it.
- Do NOT just toss a salt in there, hash it and store that.
- DO use a certified algorithm that someone else has already vetted the
  security of to protect your user's passwords.

Examples of such are bcrypt, which is based on Blowfish and PBKDF2, which is based on a hash algorithm like SHA-256.

This question over at security.stackexchange.com covers all the relevant details of the two and their tradeoffs.

[Do any security experts recommend bcrypt for password storage?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4781/do-any-security-experts-recommend-bcrypt-for-password-storage)

You may also benefit from reading [How to safely store a password](http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/).